# What was the name of Baird Whitlock's character in the meta-movie in Hail, Caesar?

Tags: character, hail-caesar, ben-hur

What was the name of Baird Whitlock's character in the meta-movie in *Hail, Caesar!*? The reason I ask is I just saw Timur Bekmambetov's [Ben-Hur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben-Hur_(2016_film)) and I was trying to recall if Cloony's character in the the Coen Bros' meta-movie was the same as the centurion in Ben-Hur. *(The Coens seemed partly to be drawing on the classic Ben-Hur for their meta movie.)*

Answer (score 2):

**Autolycus Antoninus**

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475290/movieconnections):

> O Brother, Where Art Thou? (2000) 
>   In "Hail, Caesar: A Tale of the Christ" Baird Whitlock (George Clooney) plays **Autolycus Antoninus**. In the Coen Brothers' earlier movie "O Brother, Where Art Thou", which is loosely based on Homer's Odyssey, George Clooney plays Ulysses Everett McGill. In Greek mythology Autolycus was Ulysses' grandfather.

(bolding mine)

Comment: Loosely based is right. I heard an interview with the Coen's where they said they petered out after reading about 1/2 of the Odyssey. Great movie nonetheless!